# Chromium print without dialog (Default printer) Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, webbrowser-control, chromium

I'm implementing chromium control in my C # winforms application, I need to print the page without the dialog box, ie make use of the default printer.

```
   #region members


    ChromiumWebBrowser chrome;

    #endregion

    public PrepaidVirtualOfficeForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://ourcodeworld.com");
        chrome.LoadingStateChanged += OnLoadingStateChanged;
        this.pnlContainerBrowser.Controls.Add(chrome);
        chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

 private void mtPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chrome.Print();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot print silently, CEF does not support that option.

See [General-Usage#printing](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#printing)

You can print to pdf and then print that from your code